# Conditional uptake of @Controller based on Configuration switch

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, conditional-statements, controller

I'd like to choose 1 of 2 classes for a `@Bean` based on a system property using basic spring. A very watered down variant would look like this

```
@Configuration(value = "BipBop")
@EnableWebMvc
public class BipBopConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    
    @Bean
    public BipBop getBipBop() {
        if (Boolean.getBoolean("isBip")) {
            return new Bip();
        } else {
            return new Bop();
        }
    }
}

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/bipbop")
public class Bip implements BipBop {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void bipBop(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        try (PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(response.getOutputStream()))) {
            pw.println("Bip");
            pw.flush();
        }
    }
}

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/bipbop")
public class Bop implements BipBop {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void bipBop(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        try (PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(response.getOutputStream()))) {
            pw.println("Bop");
            pw.flush();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem I see is that while the `@Bean` picks the correct implementation, it doesn't see the chosen class as a `@Controller`, and so when you hit the server with `/bipbop` you get 404s.

If both classes are on the scan path, then spring recognizes them as controllers, but then complains that there is a conflict for `/bipbop` with two implementations.

How do tell spring to do this? I see the `@ConditionalOnProperty` but that seems to be only for spring boot from what i can tell.

Comment: What about `@ConditionalOnMissingBean`? and I'm not sure what do you mean by `only for spring boot`, are you looking for a solution that should work outside the spring?

Comment: i thought ConditionalOnProperty was only available in spring boot, not spring-mvc, am i wrong? What jar is it in?

Comment: oh.. got it, you're right. What about `@Conditional`? which is available in `spring-context` jar

Comment: ah @Conditional, yeah that works thanks!

Comment: Happy that @Conditional worked and solution has been provided. But only curious, why do it on controller level as opposed to creating a polymorphic component and then injecting it to the controller?

Comment: Glad it worked. I added and expanded on this in answer so that it will be helpful to someone else in the future.

Comment: this was an existing spring boot app that i had to convert to standard spring app, as spring boot went on the banned tech list at my company.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to conditionally enable a controller based on a property value from a properties file in a Spring application, you can use `@Conditional`:

Assuming you have a controller class named `MyController`:

```java
@RestController
public class MyController {

    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String hello() {
        return "Hello from MyController!";
    }
}
```

Now, let's conditionally enable this controller based on a property value:

```java
@RestController
@Conditional(MyControllerCondition.class)
public class MyController {

    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String hello() {
        return "Hello from MyController!";
    }
}
```

Notice the addition of `@Conditional(MyControllerCondition.class)` on the `MyController` class. Now, let's create the `MyControllerCondition` class:

```java
public class MyControllerCondition implements Condition {

    @Override
    public boolean matches(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {
        // Access the property value from the environment
        String enabledPropertyValue = context.getEnvironment().getProperty("my.config.enabled");

        // Check if the property is defined and has the value 'true'
        return "true".equalsIgnoreCase(enabledPropertyValue);
    }
}
```

This condition class checks whether the property `my.config.enabled` is defined and has the value 'true'. If the condition is not met, the `MyController` class won't be applied.

Remember to load the properties file in your Spring application. You can use the `@PropertySource` annotation on your main configuration class or through the `application.properties` or `application.yml` files.

```java
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:myconfig.properties")
public class AppConfig {
    // Configuration for loading properties file
}
```

Now, the `MyController` will be conditionally enabled based on the property value, allowing you to control its activation in different environments.